# How to publish a .NET application without debug information, OneClick or any other type of installer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, oneclick

I want to simply publish my .NET application into a folder without any debug files, any debug information in the executable, any installer like OneClick or Wix and as optimized as possible. How can I achieve this in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Have you tried publishing from the project Properties|Publish tab. You can publish to a local folder and push that to a website and you will have a OneClick installation.

Comment: In my question I'm specifically saying that I don't want to use OneClick.

Comment: My bad. I misread your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Properties|Build tab there is an advanced button that brings up the Advanced Build Settings dialog. You can set the Debug Info to "none". However, if you have published to the location prior to setting this flag the pdb's from the last build are not automatically removed and will remain there.

Comment: This still adds the vshost files but comes close enough. I'm gonna leave the question open a bit further to see if there's some specific other way to publish an application that entirely only copies what's absolutely needed to run it, but if there's none I'll mark this as answer.

Comment: There is the Properties|Debug Enable Debuggers section. Uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"